# putting strings together (variable plus pipe)

Tags: bash

The goal is to use a static variable and combine it with the output of a pipe.
I am looking for an one line solution !

*This is an complete overhaul of the written examples, to keep it more clean!
The old post I have removed cause of to mutch noise.*

```
link="http://example.com/"
echo "index.html" > test.file
echo "search.php" >> test.file
echo "login.js" >> test.file

cat test.file | awk 'BEGIN {var=ARGV[1];ARGV[1]=""} {print var, $0}' "$link"
http://example.com/ index.html
http://example.com/ search.php
http://example.com/ login.js

cat test.file | awk -v var="$link" '{print var, $0}'
http://example.com/ index.html
http://example.com/ search.php
http://example.com/ login.js
```

This looks like what I need, but without the nasty white space in it.
I need that field separation gone!
Option `-F''` result in error message.
Adding `| tr` or `| sed` to remove the while space seems like error correction to me.

The following solution works so far ...

```
for string in $(cat test.file)
do
    printf "${link}%s\n" "$string"
done
```

Ouptut:

```
http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/search.php
http://example.com/login.js
```

In a loop I can combine all the output of a pipe with my static variable.
But isn't there a better solution without using a loop ?

It seems approaching the pipe with `printf` doesn't work by default and I have to put `xargs` to it.

```
echo "World" | xargs printf 'Hello %s\n' "$1"
Hello
Hello World
```

Even then the output is doubled, but why ?

**I am still looking for an one line solution !**

Comment: please update the question with more details, eg: a) is the `wget` call working and if so then provide the results of the `wget` call (or at least the lines of interest, plus a few leading/trailing lines), b) are the `grep` calls working and if so then provide the results of said calls; at this point I can't tell if you're having a problem with `wget`, `grep`, `awk`, `xargs` and/or `printf`

Answer (score 1):

You pipe something into `printf`, but `printf` does not process its standard input. You can easily verify this by doing a

```
echo x | printf foo%s bar
```

which just prints foobar, and ignores the *x*.

Comment: Not sure what & mean but bash thinks it has to put it into background. `echo "World" | xargs printf 'Hello %s\n' "$1"` does what I need, but it outputs two lines. One with Hello in it and the second with Hello World. How to fix this ?

Comment: It was a typo. It's fixed now.